# How to resolve Teams bot ID change after upgrade to TeamsFX v5

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I have recently upgraded an older Microsoft teams notification bot project to teamsfx v5. After redeploying the bot to the same azure instances as before, the stored conversation references in my blob storage have some changes.

The bot id and bot name in the conversation reference are different to before and so, sending notifications to these old conversation references returns a 403 error.

I have ensured the details in the .env.dev file match what were in my old .fx files (bot id etc). This seems to have had no effect however and the new conversation references being saved still have those different bot id / name values.

I'm pretty stuck on why this may be occurring but it's a massive problem as I already have a lot of conversation references saved from installs over the past few months.

Comment: Why are you not simply able to use the old bot Id?

Comment: When upgrading to TeamsFx v5, there might have been changes in how the bot id and bot name are handled. Ensure that you are correctly updating these values in your conversation references.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a new bot app is created after your project is upgraded to Teams Toolkit v5, so the bot id is different in the conversation reference.

You may follow [this wiki](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/wiki/Teams-Toolkit-Visual-Studio-Code-v5-Guide#using-existing-microsoft-entra-app-id-for-bot) to use the old bot app in TTK v5.

Note: you need to re-publish your Teams app to make these changes take effect.